# Linking to a specific tab on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, hyperlink, tabs

On my product pages, I want to have a a link that will take the user to a specific tab below.

The three tabs on each product page are: `Description, Reviews, Order Form`.

I've created the link which is basic and appears as:

```
<a href="#tab-name">ORDER</a>.
```

The tab below is set up as follows:

```
<div id="tab-name">tab info</div>
```

A simple link like the one above doesn't work.

When someone opens a product page, the Description tab is the default open tab, which is fine.

How can I create a simple link that when clicked will take the user to the Order Form tab?

I've searched in so many places and most explanations show solutions when you link  to a specific tab on one page from another page.

I'm using WordPress as my CMS.

Does something like this need Javascript to make it work? If so, what (simple) code could accomplish this? (I'm not a developer.)

Thank you.

Comment: What library you use in your wordpress theme to buld these tabs? Please post relevant codes.

Answer (score 0):

What i understood is you have three div one after other in page and all are visible at same time. 
**Note: if at a time only one div is visible and other is hidden and on click of anchor you need to show it and than scroll to that position in that case you will need javascript**

I hope this is not your case in your case all the div are visible and on click of anchor you need to scroll to that particular div, in that case you don't need any javascript and your code should work.

Here is working demo i have made in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/vickykumarui/n2wzksdg/

sample HTML code is

```
<a href = "#div1">Go to div 1</a>
<a href = "#div-2">Go to div 2</a>
<a href = "#div3">Go to div 3</a>
<a href = "#div4">Go to div 4</a>


<div id="div1">
<h4>  somed ummy content div1</h4>
<p> somed ummy content</p>
<p>   somed ummy content</p>
    <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
</div>
<div id="div-2">
<h4>  somed ummy content div-2</h4>
<p> somed ummy content</p>
<p>   somed ummy content</p>
    <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
</div>
<div id="div3">

<h4>  somed ummy content div3</h4>
<p> somed ummy content</p>
<p>   somed ummy content</p>
    <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
</div>


<div id="div4">

<h4>  somed ummy content div4</h4>
<p> somed ummy content</p>
<p>   somed ummy content</p>
    <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
</div>
```

Now when you run the above code in jsfiddle you will observe that on click of anchor page is scrolling to respective div but on click of fourth anchor page is not scrolling to div4 that is because div4 is at bottom of page and it does not have space to scroll below.
Hope it helps

Updated above fiddle which initially hides div2, div3,div4 and on click of anchor tag it will show respective div and scroll to that position. Now changed code is

HTML CODE : Changes from previous code is
1. initially each function will have class display noe which is responsible for hidding div 
  and added onclick function like this  Go to div 2 this function in js is responsible for showing div onclick of respective html

```
<a href = "#div1">Go to div 1</a>
<a onclick = "showDiv('div-2')"
href = "#div-2">Go to div 2</a>
<a onclick = "showDiv('div3')" href = "#div3">Go to div 3</a>
<a onclick = "showDiv('div4')" href = "#div4">Go to div 4</a>


<div id="div1">
<h4>  somed ummy content div1</h4>
<p> somed ummy content</p>
<p>   somed ummy content</p>
    <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
</div>
<div id="div-2" class = "displayNone">
<h4>  somed ummy content div-2</h4>
<p> somed ummy content</p>
<p>   somed ummy content</p>
    <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
</div>
<div id="div3" class = "displayNone">

<h4>  somed ummy content div3</h4>
<p> somed ummy content</p>
<p>   somed ummy content</p>
    <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
</div>


<div id="div4" class = "displayNone">

<h4>  somed ummy content div4</h4>
<p> somed ummy content</p>
<p>   somed ummy content</p>
    <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
  <p>   somed ummy content </p>
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
.displayNone{
  display:none
}
```

JS CODE

```
var showDiv = function(id){
var element = document.getElementById(id);
element.classList.remove('displayNone')
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I essentially have that setup like yours, but it's not working.When I click my link, it simply scrolls down to the bottom of the page and the Order tab that I want to open simply doesn't.

Comment: Hi Ron above code will only scroll to particular position, it wont show or hide div for that we need to add js code i will add the code and update fiddle if you wish to show or hide also.

Comment: Oh. Thank you. When you go to that page, all the tabs appear, but the Description tab is the "active" tab and open, which is what I want. But then I want to have a link within the Short Description area at the top of the page, that when clicked, takes the user and opens the Order Form tab. That's the problem I'm having. Yes. If you could add the necessary JS code, that would be so helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated fiddle have a look at them and feel free to ask further

Comment: Thank you. I actually don't want any of the tabs to be hidden when a user goes to that page. Is it possible to have all tabs show, but when a user clicks on the link to simply take them to, and open, the tab that I want?

Comment: It is always possible to show or hide any tab just we need to add the class or remove the class or showing and hiding,Now what i understood is initially all the tabs are shown and on click of anchor only that particular tab will be shown rest all will be hidden. Am i right ? I did'tn got this line please brief it "but when a user clicks on the link to simply take them to, and open, the tab that I want?"

Comment: No. I have three tabs on my products pages: Description, Reviews, Order Tab. All I want to do is put a link in the Short Description area above that when clicked will take the user to the Order Tab (with the Order Tab open). RIght now I have a link, but it doesn't work unless the Order Tab is open.

Comment: can you please attach the screenshot of application before click and what is requirement after click.That will be helpful